# Influxdb: How can I modify all values in a field? (divide current value by 100,000)

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have a lot of pressure data registered in Pa, but it should be in Bar (100,000 Pa).

How can I modify all values in a field in my Influxdb to be divided by 100,000?

What I would have done in MariaDB:

```
UPDATE table SET pressure = pressure / 100000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot update a row but you can overwrite it (by the exact timestamp)
just  use the same insert wite same timestamp (un nano)
e.g.

```
insert tests,tag=tag pressure=200000 1505799797665800000
insert tests,tag=tag pressure=2 1505799797665800000
```

of coarse you should read the values before